# Convergence of this sequence formed by ratio of terms of the sequence ${x_n}=\frac {n!} {n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider a sequence ${x_n}=\frac {n!} {n^n}$, then $a_n=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ converges to which number?
My attempt at this problem was:
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}.\frac{n^n}{n!}=(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$$
so basically, I needed to evaluate the limit of this expression when n approaches infinity, which I evaluated as:
$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}e^{n\log_e\frac{n}{n+1}}$$
$$n\log_e\frac{n}{n+1}=-n\log_e\frac{n+1}{n}=-n\log_e(1+\frac{1}{n})$$
Thus puttin
$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}-\frac{\log_e(1+x)}{x}=-1$$
So I came to the conclution that
$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}e^{n\log_e\frac{n}{n+1}}=e^{-1}$$
But the answer provided in the answer key is 1. What step did I do wrong to arrive at this conclusion? Or is the anwer key erroneous?

Comment: In your first expression I believe you meant writing $(n+1)^{n+1}$ in the first denominator.

Comment: @Snaw Yes I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct since
$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ tends to $e$.